# How to verify when a profile was assigned to an user Oracle Server

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

How can I verify and list when a profile was assigned to an user in Oracle Server?

I know the profile using the query:

```
SELECT username, profile
FROM dba_users;
```

But I need to know WHEN the profiles were assigned to the users, example: Have 2 profiles: "default" and "default2", I assigned to the user "John" the profile "default" on 17/02/2020, and for the user "Bill" assigned the profile "default2" on 20/02/2018, I would like to list these dates in a query.

Thanks!

Comment: pretty sure you would need to enable auditing or write a trigger to capture that yourself

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: check the oracle auditing docs, and you'd want to enable auditing 
 https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-94381464-53A3-421B-8F13-BD171C867405

Comment: I had a go at this, you CAN audit the USER statement, which would capture who/when did an ALTER USER ... PROFILE ... but the audit trail doesn't capture the profile name, or even the exact SQL used to assign the profile.

Comment: Sure, audit way would'nt work for me... So for WHEN an user was authorized for a ROLE, is needed audit trail too?

Comment: I'd probably look at creating a stored procedure that assigns profiles to users, and build rules around that - then in your SP, you could add some code that would update tables with the point in time they were assigned